Inverse of a Block matrix formed by two column blocks which represent orthogonal complements
I have got a matrix $B$ $m \times n$ with rank $m$. I found then the basis of its kernel and of its rowspace. Both together form a basis of $\Re^n$. With this I make the change of basis matrix $P$ which is formed by two column blocks, the first one is the basis of the rowspace of $B$ and the second one is the basis of the kernel of $B$. Now I want to find the inverse of the block matrix $P$ by blocks so I can apply the change of basis to another matrix $A$ operating by blocks by the formula $P^{-1}AP$.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
